# UITableView scroll changes cell background color swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell

I have cells with white backgrounds with what is normally thin clear divider between them, but ive made the diver red to highlight what happens.

It starts off right, but when I scroll it changes the colour of the cells to the divider colour and keeps changing.

See the image for further clarity of what i want.

[image: What i want when i scroll and what i start with]

See the image of what i end up with.

[image: After scrolling up and down it updates to this]

Below is the code from my cellForRowAtIndex:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell  = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for : indexPath) as! CustomCell


    let bgColorView = UIView()
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.withAlphaComponent(0.15)

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView


    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            cell.titleLabel.text = problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].getTitle()
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].getMessage()

            //print("status is \(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].status)")

            if(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].status == 0){
                cell.statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            }
            else{
                cell.statusLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 28/255.0, green: 121/255.0, blue: 125/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            }
            cell.statusLabel.text = problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].calculateSolved()
            cell.messageCountLabel.text = "\(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].commentCount)"
            cell.distanceLabel.text = "\(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].getDistance())km"
            cell.problemImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NoImage")


            if(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].image_url != ""){

                print("runs imageeee")
                var storage = FIRStorage.storage()

                // This is equivalent to creating the full reference
                let storagePath = "http://firebasestorage.googleapis.com\(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].image_url)"
                var storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: storagePath)




                // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
                storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 30 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                    } else {
                        // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            cell.problemImage.image  = UIImage(data: data!)!
                        }
                        print("returned image")
                    }
                }


            }

            else{

                cell.problemImage.image  = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NoImage")

            }

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white



            }


        else{

            cell.titleLabel.text = problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].getTitle()
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].getMessage()
            //print("status is \(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].status)")

            if(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].status == 0){
                cell.statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            }
            else{
                cell.statusLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 28/255.0, green: 121/255.0, blue: 125/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            }
            cell.statusLabel.text = problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].calculateSolved()
            cell.messageCountLabel.text = "\(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].commentCount)"
            cell.distanceLabel.text = "\(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].getDistance())km"
            cell.problemImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NoImage")


            if(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].image_url != ""){

                print("runs imageeee")
                var storage = FIRStorage.storage()

                // This is equivalent to creating the full reference
                let storagePath = "http://firebasestorage.googleapis.com\(problems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row - indexPath.row / 2].image_url)"
                var storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: storagePath)




                // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
                storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 30 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                    } else {
                        // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            cell.problemImage.image  = UIImage(data: data!)!
                        }
                        print("returned image")
                    }
                }





            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


        }


    }
    }
    else {

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        cell.titleLabel.text = ""
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = nil
        cell.statusLabel.text = ""
        cell.distanceLabel.text = ""
        cell.problemImage.image = nil
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

    }


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Does this code compile at all? And remove all `as NSIndexPath` casts (not related to the issue).

Comment: Yes compiles fine, functionality okay, but just the colour switching around when you scroll is not good for the user interface and looks @vadian

Comment: The code you posted does not compile, the braces are not (or badly) balanced.

Comment: @vadian i have put the exact code now, i tried to remove the bulk to make understanding the issue a bit easier

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
tableView(_:shouldHighlightRowAt:)
```

And this:

```
tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)
```

And unhighlighting

```
tableView(_:didUnhighlightRowAt:)
```

To modify your cells selection, don't forget to conform to the UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: this seems like a lot  considering it was already working @MEnnabah.  All i did was put the logic for loading images into this function and its made all this happen,was working flawlessly before those lines went in

Comment: I'm really not sure, you need to view the hierarchy to know what is the red color, is it the contentView of the cell or something else. One more thing, you really need to create views and network request outside the cell dequeueing.

Comment: Yes it will be the red background i set at the bottom of the function and i was just told to put the network request inside the cell dequeueing haha, confusing answers